# Use List elements inside the form as and get parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, powershell

Is there any way to use an editable list like a `<ul><li</li></ul>` to use in a form?
I want that the user is capable of editing the list and get the value.

Is there a way with jQuery or JavaScript to do that?

I want the form to submit the list as a result as items.

Comment: How is PowerShell relevant?

Comment: `ul` isn't directly "editable", but you can certainly use something like an `input` and some js to generate html to append to a `ul`.   To submit you could either re-read the html at time of submit or populate a single or multiple hidden inputs at the time of generating the html (easier for form submit).   Have a go and when you have a more specific question, come back here to ask it.

Comment: Or maybe look into `contenteditable`.

Comment: I made a form with some lists which gets replaced by a PowerShell. This creates a unsorted list with list items which are "editable" by a button and a modal function (jquery). whats needed is the save function, but the query is missing the list items.

Comment: You can use jQuery Ajax to submit the post request, and add your <li> data into it.

Comment: hey, Ajax sound interesting, is there a documentation or a tutorial how to use ajax?

Comment: Take a look at a React or Angular “todo” or “list” tutorial. They would probably achieve what you want but might be an overkill or a steep learning curve. I’d you want a framework for both the server and in the browser consider next.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for jQuery's [sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) feature. It will let you drag elements in any order and capture the array of positions. Click on *view source* on jQuery's webpage for a nice example.

Comment: Im searching more for an option to remove and add items + get them when the user presses "save" in the form or by any other method or action called.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you post the code that you started with.  What does it mean to add items.  Add list items? Please make the question clear.

Comment: i fixed it with a function that just simple add hidden inputs which then are in the HMTL Table so I can process the changes.